# Loop through posts inside WP query action?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a function that creates a query for posts to be filtered/ordered on a page. However, when this function runs, I want to loop through each of the posts returned by this query and display some text if each posts meets a certain condition. Is it possible to use get_posts() within this function in order to loop through the posts by the given query? Do I need an entirely separate function for this? I have tried doing $test = get_posts($query) but it breaks my page.

```
function connected_team_designpatent_order( $query ) {
    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }   
    
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => 'practice_area',
        'value' => 'Design Patent',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    
    $query->set( 'meta_key', "position" );
    $query->set('orderby', "meta_value_num");
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    print_r($query);

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/team_designpatent_query', 'connected_team_designpatent_order' );
```

Comment: This code doesn't _perform_ the actual query, it just sets certain parameters for the query, that will be executed later. _"I have tried doing $test = get_posts($query) but it breaks my page."_ - of course it does, that function wants an _array_ of arguments, not a WP_Query instance.

Comment: Makes sense. Do I need to create a separate function to actually run the query so I can loop through results? Or is there a way I can convert the wp_query instance to an array and run it within my existing function?

Comment: WP_Query has a `get_posts` method as well - but I really couldn't tell you if it would make sense to call it at that point, or what possible side effects this could have. And I know Elementor too little, to be able to tell what kind of hook this is actually supposed to be - and whether it manipulates WP's _main_ query here, or something else. (If it _is_ the main query, then you should be able to access it using `global $wp_query` later on.)